# Failed trying yo parse Kitchen time with date.h or chronos

Tags: date, c++17

I'm developing a C++ timestamp parser that could check if any given string can be a timestamp representation, covering various formats.

I've tested some libraries and finally, I'm using the single header one developed by @howard-hinnant.

The only problem is with the Kitchen format **03:04AM** (HH:MM<AM|PM>).

This is the code that I'm using:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{

    std::string const fmt = "%I:%M%p" ;
    std::string const time;
    std::string const name;

    date::fields<std::chrono::nanoseconds> fds {};
    std::chrono::minutes offset {};
    std::string abbrev;

    const std::string in = "3:04a.m.";
    std::stringstream ss(in);
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> result;

    date::from_stream(ss, fmt.c_str(), fds, &abbrev, &offset);
    if (!ss.fail())
    {

        if (fds.has_tod && fds.tod.in_conventional_range())
        {
            std::cout << "result hour " << std::to_string(fds.tod.hours().count()) << std::endl;
            std::cout << ". minutes " << std::to_string(fds.tod.minutes().count())<< std::endl;
            std::cout << ". seconds " << std::to_string(fds.tod.seconds().count())<< std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
         std::cout << "failed" <<  std::endl;   
    }

}
```

What I'm doing wrong, the code works great with other formats? is there a chance that parsing a date requires more fields in order to process it fully (year, month, day)?

Hope I made myself clear, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the "C" locale, [`%p` refers to one of AM or PM](https://cigix.me/c17#7.27.3.5.p7).  You have "a.m.".  Removing the '.' works for me.

There is one other caveat:  [The POSIX spec for strptime specifies that case should be ignored.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strptime.html)  And my date lib follows the POSIX spec on this.  However by default this library forwards to your std::library for this functionality.  And some implementations didn't get the memo on this.  They may not accept lower case.

If this happens for you, you can work around this std::lib bug by compiling with `-DONLY_C_LOCALE` on the command line (or set `ONLY_C_LOCALE=1` in your IDE wherever macros are set).  This tells the date lib to do the %p parse itself, instead of forwarding to the std::lib.  And it will correctly do a case-insensitive parse.  However it assumes that the "C" locale is in effect.

Comment: Indeed, adding ONLY_C_LOCALE and removing the dots worked. Thanks for the info!
Great job on that library!